# Session Variable value becoming null After write Response.Write("REDIRECT=xxx")

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have one page which handle Payment Gateway Response, PaymentReturn.aspx. In this page i am logging response and storing response into session variable and use this session variable into another page Invoice.aspx which handle invoice page... So in PaymentReturn Page, I have

```
Session["ResponseOfPayment"] =  paymentResonse as PaymentResponse; // PaymentResonse is class

Response.Write("REDIRECT=http://mydomain.com/Invoice.aspx");
```

and in Invoice.aspx I have,

```
PaymentResponse  paymentResonse = Session["ResponseOfPayment"] as PaymentResponse;

if(paymentResponse!=null)
{
  // Generate Invoice
}
```

But I am getting paymentResonse instance null.. What is going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Response.Redirect instead of Response.Write.

```
Response.Redirect("Invoice.aspx");
```

Comment: Yaa I had tried it but not lucky to work. Currently I have resolve my problem with store response in sql table field and retrieve back from already session variable which set before going to payment gateway.